# Checking all elements are finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We have a website built using AngularJS and some components take awhile to load. What I would to do is create an event that would be triggered when all components are loaded. I could use tag selector with load event. However, the custom tag for for the components may change down the road and I prefer not to rely on that. So the question is...is there a way to create an event handler that doesn't rely on tag name but will be triggered when all loadings on the page is done.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might useful to you if you use angular UI route.

**$viewContentLoading** - fired once the view begins loading, before the DOM is rendered. The '$rootScope' broadcasts the event.

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', 
function(event, viewConfig){ 
   //Do something
});
```

**$viewContentLoaded** - fired once the view is loaded, after the DOM is rendered. The '$scope' of the view emits the event.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
function(event){ 

//Do something
});
```

OR you can try angular `$window` object.

```
$window.onload = function(e) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried your first two suggestions but I tried the last one. With that one, onload is triggered while components are still loading. But I'll try the other two approach and see if they work.

Comment: If you have any other solution can you please share with us? @Charlietfl